# All possible determinants forms a complete basis

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry

How do we mathematically prove that the set of all possible excited determinants forms a complete basis for expanding the wavefunction (as in full configuration interaction)?

Comment: I think this is an interesting question, but it would benefit from your thoughts on the problem or what you have tried to arrive at a solution. @HBHSU

Comment: I have no idea how to prove that FCI is exact, but I am curious and cannot find the answer in my books or online.

Comment: A proof is given in section 2.2 of Szabo and Ostlund's Modern Quantum Chemistry. if you can't easily obtain a copy, I can summarize their argument here when I get a chance. @HBHSU